# Finding the proabability P(Y=30)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that , X is chosen uniformly from {1,2,3,..., 100} and given X= x , Y is chosen uniformly from {1,2,3,..., x} .What is P(Y=30)?
I am thinking that it is one kind of conditional probability . Am I on the right track? Help me or any hint ..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

\begin{align} Pr(Y=30) &= \sum_{x=30}^{100} Pr(Y=30|X=x) Pr(X=x) \\
&= \frac{1}{100} \sum_{x=30}^{100} Pr(Y=30|X=x)  \\
\end{align}